# Cannot initialize type 'System.DateTime' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Tags: c#

```
DateTime[] s = new DateTime { "2000:1:1", "2001:1:1", "2002:1:1", "2003:1:1" };
DateTime[] e = new DateTime { "2000:2:1", "2001:2:1", "2002:2:1", "2003:2:1" };
```

cannot initialize type `System.DateTime` with a collection initializer because it does not implement `System.Collections.IEnumerable`

Comment: You mean: What does this mean? Did you have a question?

Comment: DateTime[] s = new DateTime[] { new DateTime(2000,1,1), new DateTime(2001,1,1), new DateTime(2002,1,1), new DateTime(2003,1,1) };

Answer (score 2):

You are putting a `string` in a `DateTime[]`, just put `DateTime` structs in a `DateTime[]`:

```
  DateTime[] s = new DateTime[] { new DateTime(2000,1,1), new DateTime(2000,1,1), new DateTime(2000,1,1), new DateTime(2000,1,1) };
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot convert strings to DateTime objects implicitly. And you are missing the double square brackets after `new DateTime`.

You should do:

```
DateTime[] s = new DateTime[] { new DateTime(2000,1,1), new DateTime(2001,1,1), ....}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works ok ... Try:

```
DateTime[] e = { new DateTime(), DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(3)};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this :

```
DateTime[] s = { new DateTime(2000, 1, 1), new DateTime(2001, 1, 1), new DateTime(2002, 1, 1), new DateTime(2003, 1, 1) };
```